# Is there a way to add flv video to video.js player in Wordpress?

Tags: video.js

Video.js supports mp4, wemb and ogg formats but i think there is a trick to add flv format example: http ://jsfiddle.net/N8Zs5/18/

Answer (score 1):

That link is just an example of forcing the Flash fallback to be the initial tech tried. You can do that by passing in `"techOrder": ["flash", "html5"]` to the data-setup attribute on a video element.

However, that shouldn't be necessary for just playing back an FLV. As long as you include the type attribute with the source (`video/flv`), then Video.js should automatically use the Flash fallback for that source.

That being said, I would encourage you to try and use HTML5-friendly formats such as H.264 or WebM. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work in Wordpress.

Comment: There's no reason either of those solutions wouldn't work in WordPress...If the plugin you're using doesn't support passing through the data-setup attribute or type attribute, you can always simply add a `<video>` tag exactly how you want it by directly editing the HTML instead of using the WP wysiwyg editor.

Comment: Thank you again for answering, i'm using the direct url like this one http://r1---sn-5up-u0oe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?fexp=3300041%2C3300111%2C3300132..., its a youtube url and eminem song flv 240p but it doesn't work on Video.js but when i add the same song but change the video quality to hd mp4 720p it works because Video.js allow mp4.